# Script and Noscript tags

Tags: javascript, noscript

I have an inline script which I want to externalize but I also have noscript tags for that script. So if I externalize script, where do I put the noscript tags?

Comment: The noscript tags need to stay where they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the document, where you want the content to appear if the browser doesn't support JS. The location of the script isn't relevant.

(In general, you should avoid using `<noscript>` in favour of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) / [Progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). A browser not supporting JS at all is one of the rarer reasons for [JS failing](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html)).

Answer (score 0):

`noscript` tags will show the content if the browser doesn't support JavaScript or JavaScript is currently turned off.

put it where ever you want.

not in the external js file. It should be in the HTML file